# How to use LSTM neural network with 3D categorical input and output?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, keras, lstm

I'm trying to use Keras to train a LSTM recursive neural network capable of predicting the next note played by receiving a sequence of notes. Basically my dataset is something like this and I want my model to predict the fifth note played:

```
     Note1     Note2     Note3    Note4  |  Note5

1   [A,2,#]   [B,3,b]   [C,4,#]  [A,2,b] | [B,3,b]

2   [B,2,#]   [B,2,b]   [B,5,#]  [A,2,#] | [A,3,#]

3   [C,2,#]   [B,5,#]   [A,4,#]  [A,1,#] | [A,8,b]

...
```

Each note is an array of 3 features and all of them are categorical. I'm struggling to understand how I can feed the neural network with this information, so any help with code about how to process the data or network architecture is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to find an encoding that will convert your data into a format neural network would understand. A common approach is *one-hot encoding*: suppose you have 7 notes (A,B,C...) 3 octaves (2,3,4) and sharp flat neutral. With one-hot this becomes 3 vectors (7,) ; (3,) ; (3;) and let's take `[A,2,#] -> [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0]` in which the indices for the categories are set to 1. This is only one way of doing it, for the notes you have you would create a matrix (4, 13) which says 4 notes encoded as one-hot per category.

Another way would be make every note unique, so you would have a vector (88,) which tells the network what note it would be, `[A,2,#] -> [...0,0,1,0,0...]` only 1 where the note is set. This would increase the size of the vector obviously but should make it more *obvious* for the network. But still 88 is not a large number for computers these days. This is how [magenta](https://magenta.tensorflow.org/) encodes notes, they encode more stuff like time etc as well for more dynamics of music generation. Finally you can create a network:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(some_hidden_number_units, input_shape=(4, 88)) # 4 past notes
model.add(Dense(88, activation='softmax')) # predict one of 88 notes
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', ...)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I actually have a few more doubts regarding the second encoding you suggested, will the result of the prediction be an array of 0s and 1s just like the one used as input? And what would be a recommended size in this scenario for that first LSTM layer?

Also, on the first encoding, would the model of the network be something like:

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(some_hidden_number_units, input_shape=(4, 13))

model.add(Dense(13, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', ...)

Comment: So for the second encoding yes, the target would be a one-hot vector of size 88. For the first encoding, you need to make 3 predictions, 3 outputs using the functional API this time, and predict the note, octave and sharpness separately as they are different *categories*. I would recommend using unique notes 88, the hidden size you have to try and guess, start with maybe 64.

Comment: Sorry for another question, I'm following your recommendation but just out of curiosity, would using the first encoding involve Merge and Embedding layers?

Comment: You can enconde in say NumPy and pass to a Merge layer as the first layer. But equally you can use Embedding layer to get one-hot.